# Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1 not loading Firefox Profile I chose

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver, profile

I read everywhere that this is the code used to load an existing profile:

```
 ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
 FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

I have created one profile with that name and everything is ok. But it keeps loading the default selenium profile.

I'm using Selenium 3.0.1 with Java and Firefox 50.0.2 which is the last version in my country at least.

Any idea of why this is happening? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should put profile to capabilities at first.

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```